# How big can I make the DOM tree without degrading performance?

Tags: dom

I'm making a single page application, and one approach I am considering is keeping all of the templates as part of the single-page DOM tree (basically compiling server-side and sending in one page). I don't expect each tree to be very complicated.

Given this, what's the maximum number of nodes on the tree before a user on a mediocre computer/browser begins to see performance degradation? For example, 6 views stored as 6 hidden nodes each with 100 subnodes of little HTML bits.

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short of it is, you're going to hit a bandwidth bottleneck before you'd ever hit a DOM size bottleneck.

Well, I don't have any mediocre machines lying around. The only way to find out something like that is to test it. It will be different for every browser, every CPU.

Is your application javascript?

If yes, you should consider only loading in the templates you need usinx XHR, as you're going to be more concerned with loadtime for mobile than performance on a crappy HP from 10 years ago.

I mean, hearing what you describe should be technically reasonable for any machine of this decade, but you should not load that much junk up front.

Comment: Correct it's all javascript. I noticed the Flow app has all of the templates pre-loaded in the DOM (see http://www.getflow.com/) and performance is splendid, so it appears worth considering.

Comment: updated answer. I think most would agree. I'd see no problem with 5000+ nodes in anything newer than IE6/7.

Comment: seems reasonable, and agreed i think it does require testing. but hopefully we all do testing before production ;) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A single page application doesn't necessitate bringing all the templates down at once. For example, your single page can have one or more content divs which are replaced at will dynamically. If you're thinking about something like running JSON objects thru a template to generate the HTML, the template could remain in the browser cache, the JSON itself stays in memory, and you can regenerate the HTML without any issue and avoid the DOM size issue.

Comment: Are you able to suggest examples or frameworks? i'm already implementing backbone.js so the templating can be added at-will, flexibly. seems viable.

Comment: If you're asking about frameworks, that's a shopping question, not a technical one. The way your question is phrased is a technical one about performance.

Comment: If you didn't notice Rich's answer didn't directly answer my question so how does that matter? Not trolling here, but its very reasonable if he suggests a different approach